# SQL Service Broker in Azure VM

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, azure-virtual-machine, service-broker

I have enabled the Service Broker in the Azure VM running Windows Server and with a SQL Server installed. The problem althought it looks like the service is running, it does not trigger a notification back to the IIS Website via the '`SqlDependecy`'. Note that this work in the Development PC, but in the Azure VM not sure why not, what can be preventing the notification to being triggered?

Tried:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues -- ok
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Database_name'; -- ok
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[Database_name] TO [sa] -- no difference
SELECT transmission_status, * FROM sys.transmission_queue -- empty
```

Comment: While SqlDependency *uses* Service Broker, it also adds a lot to the debugging process. Have you tried just sending a vanilla message to the Service (i.e. with a `send` statement from the local instance)?

Comment: Turned ON TRUSTWORTHY to the database since saw a couple of master key errors in the log. Then in the website, removed the event 'sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDependency_OnChange;' followed by reregistering when the notification is read, that and adding protected void Application_End() with SqlDependency.Stop(conn) removed another error from the log 'The query notification dialog on conversation handle closed due...'; But still the transmission queue is empty, no joy yet.

Comment: What I was suggesting above was to take your application completely out of the equation. Can you, through raw SQL, send a message to the queue? Being able to send a SB message is a prerequisite for SqlDependency. Try the least sophisticated thing you can and build upon that.